# Fill NaN with the closest not NaN columns values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill `e` column's `NaN` with its most closest (by position from left side) `not NaN` columns' values.

```
   a    b    c    d    e
0  1  2.0  3.0  6.0  3.0
1  3  5.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2  2  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  5  6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

For example, for the second row of `e`, its most closest `Not NaN` column is `e` by position, then we take `7.0`, is it possible to do this in Pandas? Thanks.

The expected output is like this:

```
   a    b    c    d    e
0  1  2.0  3.0  6.0  3.0
1  3  5.0  7.0  NaN  7.0
2  2  4.0  NaN  NaN  4.0
3  5  6.0  NaN  NaN  6.0
4  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If answer should be simplify get all first non missing values from left side to last column use forward filling them and select last column by position:

```
df.e = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```